# Extracting values between second pair of quotes

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

I'm trying to extract a value from some output. I'm attempting to use awk to capture the value I need.

I'm using awk specifically as more of a learning opportunity than a requirement, if there's a better tool for the job I can go that way, though it has to be something available typically on Mac/Linux. (eg. jq is not available)

I have a large json blob and typically somewhere within the first 10 lines will be

```
"my_key": "my_val",
```

What I need to extract is just "my_val" (without quotes)

I've got as far as

```
awk -F'"' '$0=$4'
```

which is returning the correct position in the line but is doing so for all lines. I feel there is a cleaner solution I'm not grasping.

What is the awk one-liner for "match line that contains "my_key" then extract the value between the 2nd pair of quotes"?

Comment: maybe like `awk -F'"' '/my_key/{print $3}` might do the trick. Tough to say. Can you share the JSON file that is being processed here. As for the better tool for the job, you want to use `jq`. It's a tool for parsing json.

Answer (score 0):

As always As soon as I post I manage to figure it out.

In this case the following worked for me:

```
awk -F'"' '/my_key/{print $4}'
```

If I understand it correctly it is applying " as my delimiter, then matching the line containing my_key then printing the required position on the line based on the delimiter.

Comment: That'll match `"gummy_keyring","foo"` or `"apple_pie","my_key"`. If that's not what you want then post a new question with better sample input/output to get help.